# Java - regexp - capture digits but only if not preceded by a comparator

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I have a list of strings that in a pattern like this:

```
128 and 228 and alpha > 200 and bravo < 400 or charlie = 400
```

Now I want to replace all occurrences of `\d+`, except when it is preceded by a relational operator `(<|>|=)`. Otherwise the call to `replaceAll` method on the string should replace all occurrences of `\d+` with `s.$1`. So the above string would be transformed to something like:

```
s.128 and s.228 and alpha > 200 and bravo < 400 or charlie = 400
```

I have tried to achieve this with the following: `(^\d+|(?<!>|<|=)\s+\d+)` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [negative-lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism.

We want to find and replace digits which don't have

- `>` OR `<` OR `=` with space before
- but since in `200` `00` part also doesn't have `<` `>` `=` before we must add condition that we also don't want replace digits which have digits before them

So your code can look like

```
replaceAll("(?<![>=<]\\s|\\d)\\d+", "s.$0")
```

BTW: You don't need to surround your regex to create separate group so you could use it via `$1` since group `0` always contains entire match. Also look-around mechanisms are zero-length which means that they are not included in match.

Demo:

```
String text = "128 and 228 and alpha > 200 and bravo < 400 or charlie = 400";
text = text.replaceAll("(?<![>=<]\\s|\\d)\\d+", "s.$0");
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
s.128 and s.228 and alpha > 200 and bravo < 400 or charlie = 400
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo... this is exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't get the regexp to just select the digits without the space. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out, worked fine for me:

https://regex101.com/r/fU9rH6/2

Comment: Notice that second match also includes space before `228` which would make replaced string look like `s.128 ands. 228 and alpha > 200 ...`

Comment: Also you should probably read "[Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)"

Comment: Thanks for the reply... sorry forgot to mention that for the second match it was including the space as well. I didn't want that.